# MySQL statement that returns a SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, export

I need to do a dump of a table on a remote server, but I can't access the server directly. The only access I have is through PHP scripts.

Is there some way in which MySQL will return an

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')
```

statement, like what `mysqldump` will return?

I don't have access to phpMyAdmin, and I preferably don't want to use `exec`, `system` or `passthru`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81934/easy-way-to-export-a-sql-table-without-access-to-the-server-or-phpmyadmin) for another export method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) can you run mysqldump from exec or passthru
2) take a look at this: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/perform-mysql-backup-php.php

Answer (score 0):

If you can use php-scripts on the server i would recommend [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). Then you can do this from the web-interface.

Comment: You beat me to the phpmyadmin recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [PHPMyAdmin](http://phpmyadmin.sourceforge.net), it is a php based MySQL administration tool.  It supports backups and recovery for the database as well as a 'GUI' to the database server.  It works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) will [do this for you](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#faqexport).

Answer (score 0):

This

```
select 'insert into table table_name (field1, field2) values'
       || table_name.field1 || ', ' || table_field2 || ');'
from   table_name
```

should get you started. Replace || with the string concatenation operator for your db flavour. If field1 or field2 are strings you will have to come up with some trick for quoting/escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach generating a lot of separate query statements.  You can also use implode to more efficiently combine the strings, but this is easier to read for starters and derived from this you can come up with a million other approaches.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO `table_name` ";
    $fields = '(';
    $values = '('; 

    foreach($row as $field=>$value) {
        $fields .= "'".$field."',";
        $values .= "'".mysql_escape_string($value)."',";
    }

    //drop the last comma off
    $fields = substr($fields,0,-1);
    $values = substr($values,0,-1);

    $query .= $fields . " VALUES " . $values;

    //your final result
    echo $query;
}
```

See if that gets you started

Comment: My problem with this solution is that it doesn't return an accurate INSERT statement. It will, for example, enclose integers in single quotes.

Comment: Is it returning integers in single quotes or with accent graves (`)?

Comment: This line:
$values .= "'".mysql_escape_string($value)."',";
encloses ALL values in single quotes ('). Generally it isn't a problem, but it isn't as accurate as PHP's putcsv function would do it.