# PHP code to convert a MySQL query to CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

What is the most efficient way to convert a MySQL query to CSV in PHP please?

It would be best to avoid temp files as this reduces portability (dir paths and setting file-system permissions required).

The CSV should also include one top line of field names.

Comment: Why was this question closed as not constructive? This one is fine and perfectly clear.

Comment: @Alec Because some moderators here are supermoderators, you know... "With superpowers comes great responsibility!" - Uncle Ben

Comment: @finitenessofinfinity power corrupts, absolute power corrupts absolutely. Stackoverflow is an excellent example of that.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question!

Comment: Six months later and I'm using the answers to this in my website. Can this be reopened?

Comment: This _could_ be reopened, but then it _could_ be instantly reclosed as Too Broad.  Perhaps just best to leave it shut as is.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "c:/mydata.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM my_table;
```

(*the documentation for this is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html*)

or:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

$export = mysql_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_desired_name.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";
```

Comment: technically, this is tab-separated ;)

Comment: Note the use of forward slashes with `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` even on Windows.

Comment: Hii this works fine for xls format but If I try to save as CSV file it shows all the results in 1 column. I want to save this as csv file.

Comment: Among above two which one is better, safer and why?

Comment: I would tend to suggest the second option is safer as `SELECT INTO OUTFILE requires the mysql user to have access to the filesystem to  change files which is a potentially big risk.

Comment: @vinodreddy you need to specify the delimiter as "," or \t

Answer (score 92):

Check out this [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81934/easy-way-to-export-a-sql-table-without-access-to-the-server-or-phpmyadmin#81951). It's more concise than @Geoff's, and also uses the builtin fputcsv function.

```
$result = $db_con->query('SELECT * FROM `some_table`');
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
    $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
```

Comment: Yours doesn't have the column headers.

Comment: In case anyone else is as stupid as me, don't replace `php://output` with an actual filename or try to close it with an `fclose` at the end: it's not a real file, just an alias for the output stream. Anyways this answer worked perfectly for me, thanks Jrgns!

Comment: Using mysqli: https://gist.github.com/jaredrummler/2bfcf48b48d3fefd50c2

Comment: mysql_num_fields() is not working for me and headers are not being generated. Is this function deprecated or something?

Comment: I tried it, it worked but each columns is repeated twice. Why?

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))` makes columns not repeated.

Answer (score 20):

Look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) regarding the SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE syntax.

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

Answer (score 19):

An update to @jrgns (with some slight syntax differences) solution.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `some_table`'); 
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
$headers = array(); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{     
       $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i); 
} 
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
if ($fp && $result) 
{     
       header('Content-Type: text/csv');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
       header('Pragma: no-cache');    
       header('Expires: 0');
       fputcsv($fp, $headers); 
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
       {
          fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
       }
die; 
}
```

Comment: For some reason $fp returns false to me.

Comment: For modern MySQL, you can use: $headers[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result , $i)->name;

Comment: And change the other mysql_ functions to mysqli_ functions.

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like the download to be offered as a download that can be opened directly in Excel, this may work for you: (copied from an old unreleased project of mine)

These functions setup the headers:

```
function setExcelContentType() {
    if(headers_sent())
        return false;

    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    return true;
}

function setDownloadAsHeader($filename) {
    if(headers_sent())
        return false;

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    return true;
}
```

This one sends a CSV to a stream using a mysql result

```
function csvFromResult($stream, $result, $showColumnHeaders = true) {
    if($showColumnHeaders) {
        $columnHeaders = array();
        $nfields = mysql_num_fields($result);
        for($i = 0; $i < $nfields; $i++) {
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
            $columnHeaders[] = $field->name;
        }
        fputcsv($stream, $columnHeaders);
    }

    $nrows = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        fputcsv($stream, $row);
        $nrows++;
    }

    return $nrows;
}
```

This one uses the above function to write a CSV to a file, given by $filename

```
function csvFileFromResult($filename, $result, $showColumnHeaders = true) {
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    $rc = csvFromResult($fp, $result, $showColumnHeaders);
    fclose($fp);
    return $rc;
}
```

And this is where the magic happens ;)

```
function csvToExcelDownloadFromResult($result, $showColumnHeaders = true, $asFilename = 'data.csv') {
    setExcelContentType();
    setDownloadAsHeader($asFilename);
    return csvFileFromResult('php://output', $result, $showColumnHeaders);
}
```

For example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT foo, bar, shazbot FROM baz WHERE boo = 'foo'");
csvToExcelDownloadFromResult($result);
```

Comment: Thanks john very useful code. Had to modify a line for function csvFromResult. instead of while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        fputcsv($stream, $row);
        $rows++;
    }
, i had to use     while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
//        fputcsv($stream, $row);
//        $rows++;
    }

    foreach($data as $d)
    {
        fputcsv($stream, $d);
    }
 . thanks again for such a wonderful code.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Export to CSV
if($_GET['action'] == 'export') {

  $rsSearchResults = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());

  $out = '';
  $fields = mysql_list_fields('database','table',$db);
  $columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);

  // Put the name of all fields
  for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
    $l=mysql_field_name($fields, $i);
    $out .= '"'.$l.'",';
  }
  $out .="\n";

  // Add all values in the table
  while ($l = mysql_fetch_array($rsSearchResults)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
      $out .='"'.$l["$i"].'",';
    }
    $out .="\n";
  }
  // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
  header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
  //header("Content-type: text/csv");
  //header("Content-type: application/csv");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=search_results.csv");
  echo $out;
  exit;
}
```