# CSV generation having problem with ','

Tags: php, zend-framework, csv, export-to-csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP code to convert a MySQL query to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv)

Hi I am generating a csv file from mysql record seperated by "," comma. I fetch data from database and concate it in a string. I am using following code

```
for($i=0;$i<count($all_logs);$i++)
        {
            $rd=$project->fetchRow($project->select()->where('id='.$all_logs[$i]->user2project_id));
            $username=$userid->fetchRow($userid->select()->where('id='.$all_logs[$i]->user_id));
            $outstr .=$all_logs[$i]->log_date.",";
            $outstr .=$username->username.",";
            $outstr .=$rd->title.",";
            $outstr .=$all_logs[$i]->task.",";
            $outstr .=$all_logs[$i]->workdesc.",";
            $outstr .=$all_logs[$i]->hours.",";
            $outstr .="\n";
        }
        return $outstr;
```

Now what is my problem. If any column data is itself is having a " ," comma then it splits this 1 column to 2 columns. For example if my column `workdesc` is having data like this `I worked on this,that,these and those` then it will put this 1 column to 3 columns in generted csv. Any body can tell me how can I escape from this situation......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put values in quotes something like this

```
$outstr .='"'.$username->username.'",'; //output ://"somvalue contain , comma"
```

Apply this format on all the data columns and that's it.

Comment: Thanks dude... This was exactly what I was wanting

Comment: Beware: If your text now has `"` in it, you need to replace that with `""`. Neverending love of CSV.

Comment: @ZeissS: No need to replace what `htmlspecialchars` for `htmlspecialchars($data,ENT_QUOTES)`

Answer (score 7):

In order to construct a CSV file, you should not use strings concatenations.

Instead, you should use the [**`fputcsv()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function -- and if you do not want to scrite to a file, but get a string as a result, take a look at the [**users**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#100033) [**notes**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#96937), in which you'll find several possible solutions ;-)

Using that function, you will not have to deal with escaping the enclosure nor delimiter yourself : all this will already be done for you.

Comment: Here is altough an good example for this: http://tumblr.com/xz41vh6uiz

Comment: one great answer I saw for fputcsv, for anybody who wants to see an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13474770/702420

Answer (score 1):

If the column data itself has comma, then you should use double quotes to escape it.

example if your columndata = "some,data"; then your csv should look like -

```
col1,col2,"some,data",col4
```

So better have double quotes enclosed for your column data.