# export mysql query result to php and maintain leading zero

Tags: php, mysql, export

I want to export sql query results as table on an XLS file (or anything that can be opened as table on ms excel)

I've tried this one » [PHP code to convert a MySQL query to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv/125125#125125)

however, it removes any leading zeros on the result

how do I maintain/preserve the leading zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a single quote before the first zero, like that: `'002`

That mean you should maybe define which columns are text and which are numbers, and force every text columns to begin witha single quote. A number with 0 prefix is not a number but a text in this way.

Comment: how do I define column type without adding single quote as I can not/should not modify the data on the mysql database. In addition to that condition, the results of the query is not always has leading zeros, only some of them has it

Comment: I mean add the quote on the output, not on the database, into the while-foreach. Define an array for your columns definitions, check that the foreach loop is on that column, then prefix the output: `$value = '"' . "'" . $value . '"' . "\t";`

Comment: okay, I'll try it. one more question what is a \t ? where can I find reference on that kind of strings?

Comment: it's a tabulation, search for special characters escaping on php doc

Answer (score 1):

Suppose You want to set telephone no with leading "0" when export to CSV by PHP MySql query, Just write in result data as below

```
'="'.$result['telephone'].'"'
```

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this export lib which use a building block method like Google AppInventor?

http://www.freegroup.de/software/phpBlocks/demo.html

Comment: have not seen that yet, will look into it