# Create Spaces in a query in order to export csv file

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP code to convert a MySQL query to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv)

i'm trying to export a csv file and i'd need to create space between the fields of the database printed because everything comes as a simple row.

What i need to do is also print in the header the name of the field.. here is the code i have. First i need to export fields in a csv tab or just space between fields...

```
if ( !$result1 ) { echo mysql_error(); }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $last = end($row);
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        fwrite($fh, $item);
        if ($item != $last)
            fwrite($fh, "\t");
    }
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using [fputcsv](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead of this hassle with fwrite. The syntax is like this:

```
int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = ',' [, string $enclosure = '"' ]] )
```

For your code it would look like:

```
$fh = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
if ( !$result1 ) { echo mysql_error(); }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    fputcsv($fh, $result1, ',');
}
fclose($fh);
```

The optional `$enclosure` parameter can be used if you need to use other quotes for the string values (double quotes is standard).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply...when i insert your code it gives me this result..

fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: hi, this is just an example. be sure that $fh is your actual file pointer pointing to the file you opened with fopen. also be aware i put another fopen into the text to make it better understandable for others to see what $fh is in this example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in foreach  
fwrite($fh, $item.',');

Have a look at 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-generate-a-complete-excel-spreadsheet-from-mysql/

Comment: Hey abhi thank you, this worked :)
If it's not much to ask, i need to print in the csv file even the headers.. i mean the table field names.. how can i do it

Comment: Huh, i just noticed it duplicates the output... i mean it works fine, the space but it duplicates...