# How to add title in csv download from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

My csv download code run  correctly but i want to add title in first row of csv.But I can't.

My code

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
include('config.php');

$sql ="select county.title,beach.beach_name,beach.notice,beach.latitude,beach.longitude,beach.rainfall,beach.temperature,beach.status_id from beach as beach,county as county where beach.county_id=county.id ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {
    $data[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}

outputCSV($data);

function outputCSV($data) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($data as $rowc) {
        fputcsv($output, $rowc);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv

Comment: What do you mean you can't add the title, from your DB? `county.title` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array before dumping data into that array, like below:

```
$sql ="select county.title,beach.beach_name,beach.notice,beach.latitude,beach.longitude,beach.rainfall,beach.temperature,beach.status_id from beach as beach,county as county where beach.county_id=county.id ";

$data[] = array("title","Beach Name","Notice","Latitue","Longitude","RainFall","Temperature","Satus ID");

$result = mysql_query($sql);
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){

$data[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}
```

Comment: I implement your logic but have warning 
<b>Warning</b>:  fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array