# Exporting MySQL Table to CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to export a MySQL table to a csv file.
I am using the following query which I think is correct:

```
SELECT *  
INTO OUTFILE 'result.csv'  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY 'n'  
FROM Table
```

However I get the following error message from MySQL when I try running the query in the SQL query box of phpmyadmin:

```
1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I contacted my host and he could not figure it out since it looks like I have all the right permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your MySQL user does not have `FILE` privileges. Which means it cannot save output to a file.

```
GRANT FILE ON [database_name].[table_name] TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

**EDIT:** Ignore above. Just looked this up & it seems you cannot grant `FILE` to just one database.  More [details here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//privileges-provided.html#priv_file). So you need to do this instead:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

And if your ISP does not grant you `FILE` access, then perhaps some of the PHP code based tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv) can help.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I even get the message when I try your query (GRANT FILE).#1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same "access denied" message.

Comment: @user3573826: Many shared hosting providers won't provide you with this privilege, for security reasons.

Comment: My provider does not want to provide me with the FILE privilege. any work around it?

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [Causes of Access-Denied Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/access-denied.html):

> If you are able to connect to the MySQL server, but get an `Access denied` message whenever you issue a [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) or [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) statement, your entry in the `user` table does not have the [`FILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege enabled.