# export data into CSV format and store the csv file in the server

Tags: php, mysql, csv

how to save a csv file in server itself containing the data fetching form mysql dtatbase? i want to download a database in csv format.I am able to download the contants directly, but I need to save all the fetched data into server itself and provide the user a link to download the data into xls or csv format. 
I am new to this field and I really don't have any idea how to save the CSV file in server itself.

Comment: Can't you simply write your CSV content in a new file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can first query the database with required conditions and write the contents into a CSV file on your application server & later on provide a link to this file in your application. You may check the following link on how to obtain data, convert to CSV & write to file :

[PHP code to convert a MySQL query to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create file using CSV separator i.e `;`
2. Create downloading page, you have to set some headers
3. Download
   All.

Answer (score 0):

You can write fetched data in a file and then can save this file your server.

There are many php libraries for this job. I Personally use PHPExcel. You can download it from:
https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/