# Create and download CSV file in one script

Tags: php, http-headers, download

I want to create and download a CSV file, in one script.

Up to now I have been avoiding my lack of knowledge by pre-creating the file with a cron job and then 
downloading the file via a link.

I have this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$get_members_csv_query = "SELECT * FROM members";
$get_members_csv_result=$conn->query($get_members_csv_query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

$all_members_array = array();

while ($get_members_csv_array = $get_members_csv_result->fetch_assoc())
{
    array_push($all_members_array, $get_members_csv_array);
}


$file = fopen('members.csv', 'w');                              
  fputcsv($file, array('email', 'First Name', 'Surname', 'Gender','DOB','Registered On','Country','paid','Children','Wants Kids','Relationship','Body Type','Height','Smoke','Drink','Phone','Region','Religion','Community'));      
  foreach ($all_members_array as $row) {
        fputcsv($file, $row);              
  }


      exit();
```

This creates the file successfully, but what do I need to add to the script to make it automatically download the CSV file once created?

I have tried putting this at the start if the script:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=members.csv");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
```

But it downloads the file before the script finishes (or even starts) creating the file.

I have tries putting the headers at the end of the script and using ob_start() at the top - same result.

Thanks

Comment: See this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498403/exporting-data-from-database-in-php-and-the-file-format-for-excel-export-should/25498691#25498691)

Answer (score 0):

You're never sending the contents of the file to the browser. It should be:

```
$file = fopen('members.csv', 'w');                              
fputcsv($file, array('email', 'First Name', 'Surname', 'Gender','DOB','Registered On','Country','paid','Children','Wants Kids','Relationship','Body Type','Height','Smoke','Drink','Phone','Region','Religion','Community'));      
foreach ($all_members_array as $row) {
    fputcsv($file, $row);              
}
fclose($file);

// Download file
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=members.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile('members.csv');

exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
From the exit() line, modify to:

```
exit(dnl("members.csv"));//call dnl function
```

then on the same page write the dnl function:

```
function dnl($fn){
 // Send Header
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");;
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$fn"); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
}
```

Remember that the content-type "application/octet-stream" can be changed to match only csv as you have done before.