# Getting table names from database and outputting them to html table for download

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to get data from a mysql database. This is the code that I have so far:

```
include 'sqlConnection.php';
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM PrimeSelectScan";
$rs = $sqlTableConnection->query($strSQL);
if ($sqlTableConnection->query($rs) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $sqlTableConnection->error;
} 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) 
{
    echo "\t<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['cost']."</td><td>".$row['roi']."</td></tr>\n";
}
$sqlTableConnection->close();
```

The `sqlConnection.php` file is just the connection to the database. I am not exactly sure if I am correct or not. If someone could help me out and lead me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. This is the first time I have attempted to get information like this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any error messages?

Here is an example for a mysqli query:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
$query  = "SHOW TABLES FROM primeselectscan";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILE-NAME-HERE.txt");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo "\t<tr><td>".$row['Tables_in_primeselectscan']."</td><td>\n";
}

$mysqli->close();
```

If you are wanting the actual table names within the database then you need to change your query to use 'SHOW TABLES FROM dbName'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html for details.

To have it output as an actual download add the following headers before you output anything, I added that to the code section above.

Comment: Do I have to save the file down for the user to download it?

Comment: They can save it from the browser, if you want to have it be an actual download then you will need to change the file headers and output format based on what kind of file you want.

Comment: Alright, and the tables are not being shown. I am using `SHOW TABLES FROM PrimeSelectScan`

Comment: Is PrimeSelectScan the database name or table name?

Comment: primeselectscan is the database name

Comment: I edited the answer, SHOW TABLES uses the db name in the key.

Comment: This is the current error that i receive: Notice: Undefined index: Tables_in_PrimeSelectScan in J:\...\file.php on line 8

Comment: Try Tables_in_primeselectscan for the index. You can also do a print_r($row) to see the exact index.

Comment: it was in array position 0. It now prints, now I need to download it. I am not sure how i do this. You said that i would add headers? How would i go about doing this? For example: One of the table names is candlewarmers

Comment: I added the headers into the code sample that will make it a download

Comment: So, if i make it a downloadable link, How would i set that up? I am very new to coding, Thank you for baring with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105752/discussion-between-majicbob-and-robert).

Answer (score 1):

First of all your heading says get table names for output so I am answering that.  However, it doesn't look like that's what you're trying to do in your code

....  If getting table names IS what you want..  You can use

`$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";`

Then loop through:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<a> tag and <tr><td> stuff" . $row[0] . "end </td></tr> stuff";
}
```

Comment: How do I download the table?

Comment: what exactly do you mean "download?  As in a text file?

Comment: I would like to have the file downloaded by the client as a csv

Comment: This answer should solve the "rest" of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv