# PHP: download a file after the headers have already been sent

Tags: php, http-headers

I have a number of PHP scripts which work together to generate a table of data and I would like to allow my users to download this data. Here's the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv) for this feature.

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
```

The problem is that my page's headers have already been sent and retooling the various scripts to buffer all the content would be too complex. Is there a way this can be accomplished with the headers having already been sent?

Comment: It needs to be a separate request. Create a file that only downloads the file and add a link to it on your current page.

Comment: You can't offer a page and a file for download in the same request. The download request from the browser needs to be separate from any attempt to load a new page (or refresh the current one). The browser will assume all the content is part of one type of response. One of the jobs of the response headers, you'll notice, is to tell the browser which type of content it's receiving (in order to give it some hints about what to do with that content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply enough, no

what you could do is redirect the request to a new request which is a standalone download script

As headers have already been sent, all you can really do is give your users a link to follow, perhaps with some Javascript to automatically follow the link, or perhaps an old school "meta refresh" in your HTML head

eg

https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-redirect-a-web-page-in-html.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7; url='https://www.w3docs.com'" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>You will be redirected to w3docs.com soon!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```