gradual memory increase in long running script
I use Moodle 4.1
Need to run script with php cli which fills csv file with nearly million rows of data.
<?php
define('CLI_SCRIPT', true);

require "config.php";

use core_reportbuilder\table\custom_report_table_view;

$table = custom_report_table_view::create(264);
$table->setup();
$table->download = 'excel';
$columns = (new table_dataformat_export_format($table, $table->download))->format_data($table->headers);
[$sql, $params] = $table->getPaginatedDataSQL();

$filePath = '/var/excelreport/tmp_264_' . date("d-m-Y_H:i:s") . '.csv';

try {
    $file = fopen($filePath, 'w');
    fprintf($file, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
    echo "File '$filePath' successfully created.";
} catch (\Throwable $throwable) {
    echo $throwable->getMessage();
    echo "Failed to create '$filePath'.";
}


$limit = 10000;
$rowCount = $table->getRowsCount();
fputcsv($file, $columns,';');
for ($offset = 0; $offset < $rowCount; $offset += $limit) {
    $chunk = $DB->get_records_sql($sql. " LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset", $params); // here $DB is global variable which comes from config.php
    foreach ($chunk as $row) {
        $row = array_values($table->format_row($row));
        fputcsv($file, $row,';');
    }
    echo "\n offset $offset memory: ". (memory_get_usage() / 1024)."KB\n" ;
    unset($chunk);
    gc_collect_cycles();
}
$table->close_recordset();
fclose($file);

Simply I fetch data chunks with size of 10000 rows from moodle's db and append to file in each iteration with fputcsv. After each iteration I echo memory usage which increases as script runs.
enter image description here
Did I miss something to free or php somehow increases its memory footprint in long running tasks? AS a solution should I execute each chunk as seperate process with exec?

You could try fflush() after the inner loop and see if that helps? Remember, PHP doesn't always free memory immediately or when you expect it. You could also try gc_mem_caches(), but I have no idea if that will even do something. Can't hurt to try.

Whatever is doing it is probably something inside of whatever $DB is.

Have you considered letting the database tools write the CSV file for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/125125/231316

Let the database do the work
Depending on the database
For MySql
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html
$exportsql = "{$sql} INTO OUTFILE '{$filePath}'";

For Postgresql
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html
$exportsql = "COPY ({$sql}) TO '{$filePath}' WITH CSV HEADER";

Then execute the SQL
$DB->execute($exportsql, $params);

