# Using a .php file to generate a MySQL dump

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the information I have:

I am working with a Linux based system using MySQL and PHP5.  I need to be able to generate a `mysqldump` from within a .php file, and then have that dump be stored in a file on the server in a location I would specify.

As I'm a PHP nooblet, I'd like someone to give me some assistance, guidance, or code, that would do what I require. This would have to be run remotely from the Internet.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx). I would use `mysqldump` by `system()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to export a SQL table without access to the server or phpMyADMIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81934/easy-way-to-export-a-sql-table-without-access-to-the-server-or-phpmyadmin)

Comment: This one helps to create mysqldump with help a php file. http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/10/php-create-mysql-backup/

Comment: Do not rely on exec() or system(), because most times they are disabled on shared hostings. Answer should implement a proper way to generate a database dump without running external programs.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can use the [**`exec()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to execute an external command.

Note: between `shell_exec()` and `exec()`, I would choose the second one, which doesn't return the output to the PHP script -- no need for the PHP script to get the whole SQL dump as a string : you only need it written to a file, and this can be done by the command itself.

That external command will :

- be a call to `mysqldump`, with the right parameters,
- and redirect the output to a file.

For example :

```
mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME > /path/to/output/file.sql
```

Which means your PHP code would look like this :

```
exec('mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME > /path/to/output/file.sql');
```

*Of course, up to you to use the right connection information, replacing the `...` with those.*

Comment: To get this to work, I had to replace `mysqldump` with `/usr/bin/mysqldump`. I also had to change `password=mystrongpassword` to `password="mystrongpassword"`.

Comment: Cybersecurity warning: DB password will be present in process name and available for any one that can access the process tree on host machine. Solutions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html

Answer (score 95):

If you want to create a backup to download it via the browser, you also can do this without using a file.

The php function **passthru()** will directly redirect the output of mysqldump to the browser. In this example it also will be zipped.

Pro: You don't have to deal with temp files.

Con: Won't work on Windows. May have limits with huge datasets.

```
<?php

$DBUSER="user";
$DBPASSWD="password";
$DATABASE="user_db";

$filename = "backup-" . date("d-m-Y") . ".sql.gz";
$mime = "application/x-gzip";

header( "Content-Type: " . $mime );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

$cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best";   

passthru( $cmd );

exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: Security concern: is that command "mysqldump .... " stored somewhere in the system? I am thinking about the fact there is the password, included, in clear.

Answer (score 35):

Take a look here: https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php ! It is a native solution written in php.

You can install it using composer, and it is as easy as doing:

```
<?php

use Ifsnop\Mysqldump as IMysqldump;

try {
    $dump = new IMysqldump\Mysqldump('database', 'username', 'password');
    $dump->start('storage/work/dump.sql');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'mysqldump-php error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

It supports advanced users, with lots of options copied from the original mysqldump.

All the options are explained at the github page, but more or less are auto-explicative:

```
$dumpSettingsDefault = array(
    'include-tables' => array(),
    'exclude-tables' => array(),
    'compress' => 'None',
    'no-data' => false,
    'add-drop-database' => false,
    'add-drop-table' => false,
    'single-transaction' => true,
    'lock-tables' => false,
    'add-locks' => true,
    'extended-insert' => true,
    'disable-foreign-keys-check' => false,
    'where' => '',
    'no-create-info' => false
);
```

Comment: The big advantage of this script is that it can be run by PHP on server A, when the DB is on server B. The approved answer is simpler, but works only when both PHP script and the DB are on the same server

Answer (score 9):

For security reasons, it's recommended to specify the password in a configuration file and not in the command (a user can execute a `ps aux | grep mysqldump` and see the password).

```
//create a temporary file
$file   = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'mysqldump');

//store the configuration options
file_put_contents($file, "[mysqldump]
user={$user}
password=\"{$password}\"");

//execute the command and output the result
passthru("mysqldump --defaults-file=$file {$dbname}");

//delete the temporary file
unlink($file);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you can find a comprehensive solution to dump mysql structure and data like in PMA (and without using exec, passthru etc.):

https://github.com/antarasi/MySQL-Dump-with-Foreign-keys

It is fork of dszymczuk project with my enhancements.

The usage is simple

```
<?php
//MySQL connection parameters
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpsw = 'pass';
$dbname = 'dbname';

//Connects to mysql server
$connessione = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpsw);

//Set encoding
mysql_query("SET CHARSET utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");

//Includes class
require_once('FKMySQLDump.php');


//Creates a new instance of FKMySQLDump: it exports without compress and base-16 file
$dumper = new FKMySQLDump($dbname,'fk_dump.sql',false,false);

$params = array(
    //'skip_structure' => TRUE,
    //'skip_data' => TRUE,
);

//Make dump
$dumper->doFKDump($params);

?>
```

works like a charm :-)

Comment: It does work - but it produces a different output than the PHPMYADMIN mysqldump. Why ? There is data missing, while my PHPMYADMIN backup  is complete.

Comment: @Ledew-de: Data should not be included in dump only if option skip_data=>true is passed as a parameter

Comment: In case someone is still interested in this solution, I have forked the project, fixed a lot of bugs and made it compatible with PHP 8.1 : https://github.com/danielmarschall/MySQL-Dump-with-Foreign-keys

Answer (score 5):

MajorLeo's answer point me in the right direction but it didn't worked for me. I've found [this site](http://www.jason-palmer.com/2009/11/php-file-streaming-with-cat-and-passthru/) that follows the same approach and did work.

```
$dir = "path/to/file/";
$filename = "backup" . date("YmdHis") . ".sql.gz";

$db_host = "host";
$db_username = "username";
$db_password = "password";
$db_database = "database";

$cmd = "mysqldump -h {$db_host} -u {$db_username} --password={$db_password} {$db_database} | gzip > {$dir}{$filename}";
exec($cmd);

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

passthru("cat {$dir}{$filename}");
```

I hope it helps someone else!

Comment: Yours here returns the output to the end user does it not?  I.E. upon execution it outputs it in a way you could copy/paste?  If so then this wouldn't achieve what the accepted answer did - just creates the file on the server so I could grab it by scp.

Comment: @ThomasW. This code does two things: it generates a file saved on server and prompt the download dialog. If you just want to store the file, then don't do the header() and passthru() part. And if you need the just the file location, you can always echo the $dir & $filename variables....No matter what you choose, you still can access the file via SCP

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are allowed to use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php),  you can execute shell commands through your PHP code.

So assuming you know how to write the mysqldump in the command line, i.e.

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [database] > [database].sql
```

then you can use this as the parameter to exec() function.

```
exec("mysqldump -u mysqluser -p my_database > my_database_dump.sql");
```

Comment: This will create a password prompt. How do I react to this password prompt via the PHP script? exec("mystrongpw"); will not work

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use PHP's system function call.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

That runs any command-line program from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php
exec('mysqldump --all-databases > /your/path/to/test.sql');
?>`

You can extend the command with any options mysqldump takes ofcourse. Use `man mysqldump` for more options (but I guess you knew that ;))

Answer (score 0):

```php
global $wpdb;
$export_posts = $wpdb->prefix . 'export_posts';
$backupFile = $_GET['targetDir'].'export-gallery.sql';
$dbhost=DB_HOST;
$dbuser=DB_USER;
$dbpass=DB_PASSWORD;
$db=DB_NAME;
$path_to_mysqldump = "D:\xampp_5.6\mysql\bin";
$query= "D:\\xampp_5.6\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u$dbuser -p$dbpass $db $export_posts> $backupFile";
exec($query);
echo $query;
```

Answer (score -1):

To dump database using shell_exec(), below is the method :

```
shell_exec('mysqldump -h localhost -u username -ppassword databasename  | gzip > dbname.sql.gz');
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the above codes worked for me. I am using windows.
Below Code worked for me...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  $tableName WHERE yourclause";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if($result){

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $myfile = fopen("daily_events_$district.sql", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

                $rowToString = implode("','",$row);
                $writeToFile = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES('$rowToString');". PHP_EOL;
                fwrite($myfile,$writeToFile);
            }
            echo "File saved successfully";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No result found";
    }
```

This will save file in your project folder according to your query whatever data you want.

Comment: This solution is essentially flawed, as it creates incorrect SQL strings

Comment: This will ignore indexes, foreign keys, events, functions, etc ...

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
    $toDay = date('d-m-Y');

    $dbhost =   "localhost";
    $dbuser =   "YOUR DB USER";
    $dbpass =   "USER PASSWORD";
    $dbname =   "DB NAME";

    exec("mysqldump --user=$dbuser --password='$dbpass' --host=$dbhost $dbname > /home/....../public_html/".$toDay."_DB.sql");


?>
```