# how to create a backup database script in php and zip it

Tags: mysql, php

what is the best way to backup a database using php and backing data from mysql,i have tried to look for tutorials online but i seem not to understand nicely well i wrote this though its not working nicely,im getting these errors and warnings

```
Warning: gzopen(backups/adminpanel/adminpanel_aggrement_1367616442.sql.gz): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\admin panel\backup.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: time in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\admin panel\backup.php on line 30
The file--backups/adminpanel/aggrement_.sql.gz--could not be opened for writing.
```

the code on line 17 and 30 is this

```
if ($fp = gzopen ("$dir/{$db_name}_{$table}_{$bu_time}.sql.gz", 'w9')) {



  echo "<p>The file--$dir/{$table}_{$time}.sql.gz--could not be opened for writing.</p>\n";
```

this is my code

```
<?php 
$db_name = 'adminpanel';
$dir = "backups/$db_name";
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    @mkdir('path/to/directory');
}
$bu_time = time();
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (localhost, root, nokiae71, adminpanel);
$q = 'SHOW TABLES';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    echo "<p>Backing up database '$db_name'.</p>\n";
    while (list($table) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        $q2 = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($r2) > 0) {
            if ($fp = gzopen ("$dir/{$db_name}_{$table}_{$bu_time}.sql.gz", 'w9')) {
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                    foreach ($row as $value) { 

                        gzwrite ($fp, "'$value', ");
                    }
                    gzwrite ($fp, "\n"); 

                }               
                // Close the file:
                gzclose ($fp); 

            } else { // Could not create the file!
                echo "<p>The file--$dir/{$table}_{$time}.sql.gz--could not be opened for writing.</p>\n";
                break; 
            }   
        }
    } 
} else {
    echo "<p>The submitted database--$db_name--contains no tables.</p>\n";
}

?>
```

how can i make this work or is there any better script i can use out there...

Comment: Try this [one](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/back-mysql-database-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, this solution uses [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), but I find it very easy so I thought it was worth mentioning. Cron may already be installed on the server you're using.

This is the command that I schedule cron to run once a night:

```
mysqldump -h URL_TO_YOUR_DATABASE.com -u YOUR_MYSQL_USERNAME -pYOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD --single-transaction YOUR_DATABASE_NAME | gzip > ~/PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_PLACE_BACKUPS/db_backup_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz
```

That's it.

This tells mysqldump to dump your whole database as sql. Then gzip compresses it. And then it's stored in a spot on your server with the date appended to the end of the filename.

If you really want to trigger it with php instead of cron you could try calling [mysqldump from php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6750595/241138).

Comment: How do i put this command into a PHP Script so that it executes

Comment: @NaveenThally if you follow the link at the end of my answer you'll see how to call it from php. You can use the `exec` command. So it would be `exec('mysqldump -h URL_TO_YOUR_DATABASE.com -u YOUR_MYSQL_USERNAME -pYOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD --single-transaction YOUR_DATABASE_NAME | gzip > ~/PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_PLACE_BACKUPS/db_backup_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz');` . Remember to put in your actual database information in place of the words in ALL_CAPS. And this will only run it on-demand. To schedule it you'll need to use cron.