# Getting 0KB of size file while backup mysql database using mysql dump

Tags: php, mysql

I am using below code to backup my database using php script but I am getting 0KB size file.
How can I backup my full database with all routines and functions?

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname='mydatabase';
$toDay = date('d-m-Y');
//exec("mysqldump --user=$dbuser --password='$dbpass' --host=$dbhost --single-transaction $dbname > D:\Sql_Backups/".$toDay."_DB.sql");
//exec('mysqldump --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpass --host=$dbhost $dbname > D:\Sql_Backup/file.sql');
exec ("mysqldump --routines --h $dbhost --u $dbuser --p $dbpass --single-transaction $dbname  > D:\Sql_Backup/db_backup.sql");
```

[how to create a backup database script in php and zip it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368081/how-to-create-a-backup-database-script-in-php-and-zip-it)
[How to backup MySQL database in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170182/how-to-backup-mysql-database-in-php)
[Backup a mysql database and download as a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751069/backup-a-mysql-database-and-download-as-a-file)

Comment: Any one give me suggestions to solve my problem..

Comment: Windows path must escape backslash ` \ ` to ` \\ ` if using double quotes. Besides that, what error do you get? What does `echo exec(...` print? Can you hit the command via command line from the same user? `>` does not pipe `STDERR` does it? Do you have log files?

Comment: @DanFromGermany echo exec(..) did't print anything.And it not return any error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few suggestion:
1. Compulsary to use absolute path for mysqldump.
2. Try using --opt (default option for mysqldump). 
Can refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html 
3.For the option, if use short form, no need to have (--). eg: --p. Use (--) when use full form. eg: 
--password. So use '-p' instead of '--p' (applied for others option too).
4. try 'shell_exec' or 'system' if mysqldump doesnt work on 'exec'.
5. try avoid have space between option and variable. Eg: -p$dbpass

Comment: can you provide a example with your suggestion.

Comment: @Sumitpatel this is the issues I encountered a long time ago in http://stackoverflow.com/q/26749853/4216992, for point 2 - 5 you can refer to link that I provided above.