# What is wrong with my export from database PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, export

Trying to export from a database with this PHP but it is not working.

The code throws the following error message:
'There was a warning during the export of dbname to ~/chooseFilenameForBackup.sql.'

Help appreciated.

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='dbname';
$mysqlUserName ='root';
$mysqlPassword ='password';
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';
$mysqlExportPath ='chooseFilenameForBackup.sql';

//DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
echo 'Database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> successfully exported to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
break;
case 1:
echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
break;
case 2:
echo 'There was an error during export. Please check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Isn't that a shell command?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750531/using-a-php-file-to-generate-a-mysql-dump

Comment: that could be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a local installation of php, I had the same error until I uploaded to my server and then it exported successfully