# MySQL Database Cloning using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database named **yourFirstDatabase** with few tables. I want to clone it to another database **yourSecondDatabase** along with the entire data.

Now I have following piece of code :

```
exec('mysqldump --user=root --password=root --host=localhost yourFirstDatabase > /var/www/dileep/jiteen/poc/shellPhp/file.sql');
```

This creates a Dump of the **yourFirstDatabase** (named ***file.sql***). Now I want to fetch the database elements from ***file.sql*** into the **yourSecondDatabase** 
For this I am using a similar code :

```
exec('mysqldump --user=root --password=root --host=localhost yourSecondDatabase < /var/www/dileep/jiteen/poc/shellPhp/file.sql');
```

But it isn't working fine and no data is imported in the **yourSecondDatabase**.

However, if I manually IMPORT the data from ***file.sql***, the data is imported perfectly fine. This means that MySQL dump (first code) is worlking fine but second code (to fetch the data) is having some issues.

PS : It is not showing any errors as such. I got these code from a similar question [FROM HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750531/using-a-php-file-to-generate-a-mysql-dump)
Any sort of help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `mysql` instead of `mysqldump`. The latter is only for producing dumps, not importing them.

```
exec('mysql --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --database=yourSecondDatabase < /var/www/dileep/jiteen/poc/shellPhp/file.sql');
```

Comment: I am waiting to MARK it as ACCEPTED. It says 'you need to wait 10 minutes to accept'. So waiting for same. I will surely do that, don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i came up with for duplicating databases using PHP and MySQLi:

```
// Database variables

$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '1234';

$DB_SRC = 'existing_db';
$DB_DST = 'newly_created_db';



// MYSQL Connect

$mysqli = new mysqli( $DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS ) or die( $mysqli->error );



// Create destination database

$mysqli->query( "CREATE DATABASE $DB_DST" ) or die( $mysqli->error );



// Iterate through tables of source database

$tables = $mysqli->query( "SHOW TABLES FROM $DB_SRC" ) or die( $mysqli->error );

while( $table = $tables->fetch_array() ): $TABLE = $table[0];


    // Copy table and contents in destination database

    $mysqli->query( "CREATE TABLE $DB_DST.$TABLE LIKE $DB_SRC.$TABLE" ) or die( $mysqli->error );
    $mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO $DB_DST.$TABLE SELECT * FROM $DB_SRC.$TABLE" ) or die( $mysqli->error );


endwhile;
```