# MySQL DB automatic backup Script

Tags: php, mysql, database-backups

i am almost new in PHP, MySQL.
i want to develop a database query/stored procedure/script by which i can do followings:
1) read a text file, where daily-backup start time and target location is written.
2) on this time, the script will be automatically executed.
3) so that there will be a backup copy created in the user specified target location.
4) additionally, i want to create an encrypted and zipped backup copy.

i have already searched for this type of requirement, but still don't find any proper solution.

please suggest me how can i do this job.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by learning programming.

Comment: @Daan, thanks. i have already learnt other scripting :) now its time to work on php. and i hope u suggest me regarding the mentioned issue. not about learning lang. thanks.

Comment: The simplest use `mysqldump` : see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750531/using-a-php-file-to-generate-a-mysql-dump

Comment: thanks @toto21. this is a manual backup approach. but i am looking for automated system. i.e. is there anything like - i can create any Agent in Mysql which will fire in a certain time and execute the sqldump related script (db-script)? i have implemented this sort of job in MS Sql Server.

Comment: Create cron job - see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php