# Inserting multiple rows with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, multiple-records

After importing a csv file, I'm trying to import the data with an insert statement, which is sending around 250 rows for one table.

The inserting, and code is working very well, but I had to print the insert query and the insert just worked till the row number 100.

PHP screen, which I import csv file data to the screen:

```
if(@$_FILES[file][type] == 'text/csv' || @$_FILES[file][type] == 'text/comma-separated-values' || @$_FILES[file][type] == 'application/vnd.ms-excel'){



if($_POST['FUNCAO'] == 'FORM_IMPORT')
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ##### UPLOAD FILE
    $uploaddir = 'gap_files/';
    @$filename="gap_files/".$_FILES[file][name];
    @$uploadfile = $filename;

    $count = 0;
    $id_linha = 0;
    $itens_po = '';
    $pos_to_import = '';

    if (!@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
    {
        print "<pre>";
        print_r($_FILES);
        print "$php_errormsg</pre>";
    }

    if(@$_FILES[file][name])
    {
        print '
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>PO</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_includes/css/padrao.css" >
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../_includes/js/padrao.js"></script>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../_includes/js/po.js"></script>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../_includes/js/label.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="div_report" style="background-color:#2B2B2B; position:fixed; top:0px; width:200%; height:200%; display:none; opacity:0.35; filter:alpha(opacity=35);">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="div_link_color" style="display:none; position:fixed;  margin-left: -300px; margin-top: -240px; left:50%; top:50%; width:600px; height:280px; background-color:#525252; text-align:center; z-index: 1000; text-align:center; border-radius: 0.4em; ">
                <center>
                <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="REPORT_EDIT_TITLE" colspan="3" align="center" id="title_box_comment"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <iframe style="width:587px; height:230px; background-color:#EAF0FA; text-align:center; text-align:center; border-radius: 0.4em; overflow:auto; border:none;" id="frame_link_color" name="frame_link_color"></iframe>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="button" name="comments" id="pre_production_comm" onclick="close_link_color();" value="Close" class="button" style="width:60px; height:30px;"></td>              
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </center>
            </div>

            <div width="100%" id="FRAMESBOTTON">
                <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="botton-apple"><img src="../img/user.png" />&nbsp;<b>Information</b>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="botton-apple" onclick="seleciona_div_po(3)"><img src="../img/help.png" />&nbsp;<b>Help</b>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="botton-apple" onclick="seleciona_div_po(9)"><img src="../img/application.png" />&nbsp;<b>Import Label</b>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">    
                    <tr>
                        <td class="titlestyle" colspan="6" align="center"><b>Labels to import</b></td>                  
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        ';

        $po = '';
        $line=1;
        $po_show = '';
        $itens_po = '';
        $factory_ids = '';
        $wrong_price = '';              
        $import_error = 0;
        $invoice_port = '';
        $invoice_number = '';               
        $number_of_invoices = 0;
        $invoice_gross_weight = '';
        $invoice_total_cartons = '';

        $total_pairs_invoice = 0;
        $total_amount_invoice = 0;
        $total_amount_discount_invoice = 0;

        $tr_check_po = '';
        $filename="gap_files/".@$_FILES[file][name];
        $handle = fopen("$filename", "r");

        $actual_po = '';

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {

            foreach($data as $varname => $value)
            {
                if($value){
                    $data[$varname]=mysql_real_escape_string($value);
                }
                else{
                    $data[$varname]="NULL";
                }
            }

            $check_if_inserted_invoice = mysql_query("select * from po_label where po_label.po = '".$data[3]."'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($check_if_inserted_invoice) == 0){

                if($line != 0){

                    $count++;

                    $itens_po .= '
                    <input type="hidden" name="iten_'.$count.'" value="'.$line.';'.$data[3].';'.$data[26].';'.$data[15].';'.$data[4].';'.$data[8].';'.$data[0].';'.$data[23].';'.$data[1].';"/>
                    <tr style="background-color:#ECEBEB;" onmouseover="ButtonRegSet(this,1)" onmouseout="ButtonRegSet(this)">
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="carton_number_'.$line.'" value="'.$line.'" readonly>'.$line.'</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="po_'.$line.'" value="'.$data[3].'" readonly>'.$data[3].'</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="carton_'.$line.'" value="'.$data[26].'" readonly>'.$data[26].'</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="EANCode_'.$line.'" value="'.$data[15].'" readonly>'.$data[15].'</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="size_'.$line.'" value="'.$data[4].'" readonly>'.$data[4].'</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="pairs_'.$line.'" value="'.$data[8].'" readonly>'.$data[8].'</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="customer_style_'.$line.'" value="'.$data[0].'" readonly>'.$data[0].'</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="material_'.$line.'" value="'.$data[23].'" readonly>'.$data[23].'</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="colors_'.$line.'" value="'.$data[1].'" readonly>'.$data[1].'</td>
                        </tr>';
                }

                $line++;


            }
        }



        fclose($handle);

        }

    $number_of_invoices++;

    print '         
    <form method="post" action="../_registers/po_import_label.php">
    <input type="hidden" maxlength="30" name="FUNCAO" value="insert_import_po" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" maxlength="30" name="itens_form" value="'.$line.'" readonly>
    <center>
    </br>
    <table class="round_sub_information_title_close" width="90%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8" class="round_sub_information_title_close" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                <div id="id_itens_invoices_'.$number_of_invoices.'" style="display:block;">
                <center>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="min-width:99%; width:99.8%;">
                    <tr class="line_grid">                          
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center">Carton Number</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center">PO</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center">Carton Code</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center">Case Code</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center">Size</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center">Quantity</td>                             
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center">Style</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center">Material</td>
                        <td class="fontrecord" align="center">Color</td>

                    </tr>
                    '.$itens_po.'
                </table>
                </center>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>';

        print '
        <tr><td class="round_sub_information_title_close" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td></tr>';
        print '</tr>
    </table>
    </center>
    </form>';
}
```

}

File: "../_registers/po_import_label.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION["uid"]){
    die(header("location: ../login.php"));
}

include('../_library/config.php');
include('../_library/opendb.php');
include("../_library/functions.php");

$s = "insert into po_label (carton,
            carton_number,
            po,
            size,
            pairs,
            colors,
            material,
            customer_style,
            EANCode) values";

for($i=1;$i<$_POST['itens_form'];$i++)
{
    $s .="('".$_POST['carton_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['carton_number_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['po_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['size_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['pairs_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['colors_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['material_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['customer_style_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['EANCode_'.$i]."'),";
}
$s = rtrim($s,",");

print $s;

return mysql_query($s) ? 'INSERTED.' : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();

include '../library/closedb.php'; 
?>
```

After import to the screen, I call the insert function to send the data to the database, it is when I got the error.

```
insert into po_label (carton, carton_number, po, size, pairs, colors, material, customer_style, EANCode) values (...),('10355000000098','98','0355CC0001','7',' 6','CAMEL','SOFT NUBUCK','CC-CRYSTALL','191644000270'),('10355000000099','99','0355CC0001','7',' 6','CAMEL','SOFT NUBUCK','CC-CRYSTALL','191644000270'),('10355000000100','100','0355CC0001','7',' 6','','SOFT NUBUCK','CC-CRYSTALL','191644000270'),('','','','','','','','',''),('','','','','','','','',''),('','','','','','','','',''),('','','','','','','','',''),(...)
```

Adding an observation: Before I updated the files in my official system, I tried and test it in the Wamp server, where everything works well.

[If i have only 100 rows, the insert works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYMHN.jpg)

[If i have more than 100 rows, you can check in the bottom that after the row 100 the insert becomes empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzyaL.jpg)

Comment: What `mysql` or `php` error you got?

Comment: Bad code. You do not use `@` operator esp. to mute warnings about inproper array keys

Comment: Mysql, from row number 1 to row number 100, everything works well, but then after that the insert became empty.  insert into po_label (carton, carton_number, po, size, pairs, colors, material, customer_style, EANCode) values (...),('10355000000099','99','0355CC0001','7',' 6','CAMEL','SOFT NUBUCK','CC-CRYSTALL','191644000270'),('10355000000100','100','0355CC0001','7',' 6','','SOFT NUBUCK','CC-CRYSTALL','191644000270'),('','','','','','','','',''),('','','','','','','','',''),('','','','','','','','',''),('','','','','','','','',''),(...)

Comment: Have you looked at the data being passed?  Does `print_r($_POST);` give all of the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should improve your below code with given

```
// Your code
for($i=1;$i<$_POST['itens_form'];$i++)
{
    $s .="('".$_POST['carton_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['carton_number_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['po_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['size_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['pairs_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['colors_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['material_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['customer_style_'.$i]."',
    '".$_POST['EANCode_'.$i]."'),";
}

for($i=1;$i<$_POST['itens_form'];$i++)
{
    // Remove POST for columns in which you have allowed null in data table
    if($_POST['carton_'.$i] != '' && $_POST['carton_number_'.$i] != '' && $_POST['po_'.$i] != '' && $_POST['size_'.$i] != '' && $_POST['pairs_'.$i] != '' && $_POST['colors_'.$i] != '' && $_POST['material_'.$i] != '' && $_POST['customer_style_'.$i] != '' && $_POST['EANCode_'.$i] != '')
    {
        $s .="('".$_POST['carton_'.$i]."',
        '".$_POST['carton_number_'.$i]."',
        '".$_POST['po_'.$i]."',
        '".$_POST['size_'.$i]."',
        '".$_POST['pairs_'.$i]."',
        '".$_POST['colors_'.$i]."',
        '".$_POST['material_'.$i]."',
        '".$_POST['customer_style_'.$i]."',
        '".$_POST['EANCode_'.$i]."'),";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As per the given comment, you should increase the length of URI. Please check below [Increase your URI limit in your apache server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestline).

but the best way to insert bulk data is `mysqldump` please see below answer for more information regarding `mysqldump using PHP` [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6750595/3367442)

Comment: @correia What is the error? Also , remove '@' from code. so you can get the error, notice, warning

Comment: The error is that, I can insert 100 rows, but after that my insert starts to come like this:  insert into po_label (carton, carton_number, po, size, pairs, colors, material, customer_style, EANCode) values ->row100('10355000000100','100‌​','0355CC0001','7',' 6','','SOFT NUBUCK','CC-CRYSTALL','191644000270'),->row101.....('','','','','','','',‌​'',''),('','','','',‌​'','','','',''),('',‌​'','','','','','',''‌​,''),('','','','',''‌​,'','','',''),(...)

Comment: I am asking for the error which MySQL or PHP show you.

Comment: On my screen I have no error. But if i try to use the insert directly in the PHPMYADMIN sql task, I got the error : The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server. But anyway, after get this error, I check my table and everything is inserted.

Comment: This answer is very low quality and demonstrates insecure coding practices.

Comment: @mickmackusa kindly provide updated answer on this. Thank you.

Comment: My point is that the snippet is recommending injection-vulnerable querying.  I cannot use this page to close future duplicates because I would never advice anyone to use this advice.  Additionally, all of those `!= ''` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please confirm whether all values coming without spaces by following function

```
print_r()
```

2) Use the trim() function to every single data passed in insert query

```
INSERT INTO TBL_NAME VALUES(
'".trim($value[0])."',
'".trim($value[1]))";
```

May it will help

Comment: Sorry, can you explain better your idea? I did not understand whats suppose to change in the code.